# Python OpenCV draw several circles and keep them

Tags: python

I'm trying to draw a circle on my webcam's image everytime I click. However, I would like circles to stay on the image, and add new circles with each new click. Is there a way to modify my current code to do this?

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
center = (0,0)

def mouseCallback(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global center

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        center = (x,y)


def draw_circle(frame, center):
    cv2.circle(frame, center = center, radius = 50,color = (0, 0, 255),thickness=5)

cv2.namedWindow('frame')
cv2.setMouseCallback('frame',mouseCallback)

while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    draw_circle(img,center)
    cv2.imshow('frame',img)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I do not find any information about how to make a shape stay on the video.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list to store the coordinates of the circles. Fast code sketch:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
circles = []

def mouseCallback(event,x,y,flags,param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        circles.append((x,y))

def draw_circle(frame, circles):
    for center in circles:
        cv2.circle(frame, center = center, radius = 50,color = (0, 0, 255),thickness=5)

cv2.namedWindow('frame')
cv2.setMouseCallback('frame',mouseCallback)

while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    draw_circle(img, circles)
    cv2.imshow('frame',img)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```